# DataGridView simply won't refresh

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2013

is there a foolproof way to force a `C# Visual Studio 2013` to refresh?

this doesn't work unless I run it on frmDomain_Load then it works, if I re-run it at any time (i.e. when I want to add some values to nDomains) it doesn't refresh.

```
public DataGridView domainDataGridView { get; set; }
public List<string> nDomains = new List<string>();

public void AddToGrid(){
    nDomains.Add("Brazil 1");
    nDomains.Add("Germany 7");
}

public void RefreshGrid(){
      domainDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
      domainDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

      domainDataGridView.ColumnCount = 1;

      domainDataGridView.Columns[0].Name = "Domain";
      domainDataGridView.Columns[0].Width = 251;

      foreach (String myDomain in nDomains)
      {
           domainDataGridView.Rows.Add(myDomain);
      }
      domainDataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: beyond your refresh issue, you shouldn't be trying to store your info in a string like that.

Comment: *(restraint) :-S i am not going to react - I just won't!*

Comment: You don't need to clear the columns. You could take a look at DataSource property of DataGridViews. Eg: domainDataGridView.DataSource = nDomains;

Comment: Why are you... *restraining*?  People are trying to help you.

Comment: because those are comments have nothing to do with the topic nor the question, and I `clearly` wrote it for brevity (come on "Germany 7?"). The real data source is strings from SQL. The column reset it to show it is simply explicitly requested

Answer (score 0):

Calling `grid.Refresh()` just causes it to do a redraw, which doesn't necessarily force it to redraw with any new data. Since the grid doesn't know the data has changed, it probably is just redrawing with the previous data.

If you change your `List(Of String)` to a `System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of String)` the grid will be notified when the data changes. This should cause it to automatically refresh whenever items are added/removed.